# Excel COUNTIF return FIRST unique value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I am designing a spreadsheet which will use formulas to extract unique data from a column whilst also ignoring empty cells.

I am using the following formula to mark data as whether it should be used, or is a duplicate

```
=IF(B6<>"", IF(COUNTIF(B7:B$35,B6),"No","Yes"),"")
```

This works, but marks the last occurrence of duplicate data as the one to use. I need to use the first occurrence to preserve my preferred order.

E.g. the current formula will extract `ABDC` from `A, B, C, D, C`, because the last `C` occurs after the `D`. I need it to take the FIRST `C` to read `ABCD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flip your locked range around, and check for "does this already exist above" instead of checking below.

To do this, change `IF(COUNTIF(B7:B$36,B6),"No","Yes")`, to `IF(COUNTIF(B$1:B5,B6),"No","Yes")` or `IF(COUNTIF(B$1:B6,B6)>1,"No","Yes")`

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much - that's done the job. I tried reversing the range before but it didn't seem to do anything. I must have made a mistake, your formula works great :-)